# How to use tweepy STREAMING API with a proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, httpconnection, tweepy

I am aware there is a patch for using the REST API with a proxy and it works for me. But the Streaming API uses a HTTPConnection which cannot be emulated by urllib and urllib2 (as far as I know). Is there any fix for this?

I tried using proxy with port, but it did not work.
In the streaming.py file, line 153.

```
    if self.scheme == "http":
                conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(self.api.proxy_host,self.api.proxy_port, timeout=self.timeout)
            else:
                conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.api.proxy_host,self.api.proxy_port,timeout=self.timeout)
            self.auth.apply_auth(url, 'POST', self.headers, self.parameters)
            print conn.host
            conn.connect()
            conn.request('POST', self.scheme+'://'+self.host+self.url, self.body, headers=self.headers)
            resp = conn.getresponse()
```

And, **"self.scheme+'://'+self.host+ self.url"** corresponds to - https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length

I get this error in return -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2538,    in run_code
exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
File "<ipython-input-3-4798d330f7cd>", line 1, in <module>
execfile('main.py')
File "main.py", line 130, in <module>
streamer.filter(track = ['AAP'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 305, in filter
self._start(async)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 242, in _start
self._run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 159, in _run
conn.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL      routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a github patch that enabled streaming api via proxy. It works just fine!

https://github.com/shogo82148/tweepy/blob/64c6266018920e0e36c6d8d1600adb6caa0840de/tweepy/streaming.py

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy currently does not support using a proxy. However, support for proxies should be coming in the next few days. I'll update this answer with more information.